# Leaky Meyers Singleton: is it threadsafe?

Tags: c++, thread-safety, singleton, c++20

I implemented a Meyers Singleton, then realized it could be vulnerable to the destructor fiasco problem.

As a result, I changed the code to be:

```cpp
Instance *getInstance()
{
    static Instance* singleton = new Instance();
    return singleton;
}
```

After implementing this, and no apparent bugs occuring, a coworker was implementing a different singleton and used `std::call_once` instead.

I've now realized that after much searching, I couldn't find if the "Leaky Meyers Singleton" is a threadsafe pattern. Should the leaky singleton be changed to `std::call_once`? Or is it threadsafe as-is?

Is the pointer considered a "block-scope" variable? If so I think it would be thread-safe, but if not there's significant bugs introduced with the current leaky singleton approach.

Comment: Thread-safety doesn't depend on whether it's a pointer or not, so you should be safe.

Comment: Why not `
    static Instance singleton;`

Comment: [Meyer's Singleton](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1008289/3807729) is indeed thread safe (after `C++11`). I think there are only some obscure circumstances when destructor fiasco could be an issue. For that you could use `std::shared_ptr` https://stackoverflow.com/a/40337728/3807729

Comment: If you follow @JVApen 's suggestion I don't think you will suffer from a destructor fiasco unless you have some other instance of something alive that depends on the above `Instance` to be alive after it's been destroyed ...

Comment: Your code has an unneeded new in it meyer's singleton returns a reference.  *Instance& getInstance() { static Instance instance; return instance; }* Your code will be detected by many tools as a memory leak since the singleton instance will never be deleted (there is no matching delete call). The version returning the reference WILL call the destructor of Instance at shutdown of your program

Comment: The best suggestion is to stop using singletons

Comment: @Taekahn Well I would say use with extreme care. But indeed I would recommend designs using dependency injection (at least if you want to be able to write unit tests)

Comment: @pepijn Valgrind and Address Sanitizer both don't report it as an error. It seems probable they support the leaky singleton problem.

Comment: There were reasons singletons were chosen. There is a color wrapper for standard out where DI doesn't help the nature of the test and the added parameters polluted the API everywhere... The other singleton was to centralize error handling and safe application shutdown across multiple threads. DI started being a nightmare to maintain for that, so a singleton it became.

Comment: @Ted as it's a global error handling singleton (simplified for post ofc), there's a large possibility that another static object of indeterminate initialization will in the future depend on it when the static destructors fire off. I have dealt with static destructor issues in the past (double symbol include from SO and main binary) and never want them in the future lol. All you get is a symbol error with no stack trace, it's horrific. 

Comment: @ListsOfArrays It's so long ago I used singletons with a pointer but I remember MSVC debug builds reporting it as undeleted memory thats why :)  And I can relate to DI polluting an constructors too (usually I create some kind of DI context structure for and put interfaces in that and pass those around) In the end its all engineering and choosing appropiate tradeoffs. Anyway seems you've giving it more then enough thought!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is thread-safe: no two threads will ever try to initialize the same variable with static storage duration at the same time.  That includes the entirety of evaluating the initializer.

Comment: Thanks! Now I don't have to worry about refactoring the code. 

Comment: @ListOfArrays, not only that, some even reported static to be faster than the equivalent code with call_once. https://youtu.be/15etE6WcvBY